# Construct a DNS Query and send it to specific DNS Server

Tags: android

I want to write a simple app that would send a dns query to specific dns server ip and get a response for me.

Can someone point me to a code or give me a sample code that I could use in android.

I am not even sure if we can do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) -- the `ExtendedResolver` is likely what you want (assuming the platform will let you in plain java).